# How to parse null values in unordered JSON object using JMeter

Tags: json, web-services, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jsonpath

We are receiving a JSON response from a web service - which we can easily parse using [JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/) when running tests. 
The problem that we recently found is that the fields in the JSON object are not always in the same order. Therefore, regex will break.

**Here are the solutions we have tried:**

**1.)** [JSON path extractor](http://www.beanshell.org/) (from jp@gc):
This is pretty cool and lets you choose the element that you want. The problem is that when there is a `null` value, it won't read it at all.

**2.)** Then we tried adding a [BeanShell](http://www.beanshell.org/) -pre-processor to set the variable to `null` initially, so that when it reaches the conditional it is executed properly. The problem with this approach is that once set to `null`, it won't change to anything if a value is picked by the JSON path extractor.

Does anyone have any ideas on other ways I could get this to work? Let me know if you have any questions or need clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I have done in one of you test case as an alternative.

```
- HTTP Sampler
 - BSF Post processor with javascript language
    - script in BSF goes like this
      - log.info("processing image index response");
if ("" != prev.getResponseDataAsString()) { //if response is not empty process it
    eval( 'var indexJSON = ' + prev.getResponseDataAsString() ); //get the respnose JSON string as javascript var and operate on it as you like
    vars.putObject("indexJSON", indexJSON);

    var next_slide_timestamp=indexJSON[0].timestamp;
    vars.put("next_slide_timestamp", "0");

    var maxSlides=indexJSON.length;
    vars.put("maxSlides", maxSlides);
} else { //if response is empty simply initialize all var to 0
    vars.put("currentThumb", "0");
    vars.put("currentSlide", "0");
    vars.put("next_slide_timestamp", "0");
    vars.put("maxSlides", "0");
                          log.info("index time : empty response , setting defaults to zero");
}
```